# Metric Space Axioms

Tags: metric-spaces

I've been reading about metric spaces recently and had a question about the definition. Everywhere I've seen, we take a metric space to be a set $E$ equipped with a metric, a binary map $d:E\times E\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, where $\forall x, y, z\in\mathbb{R}$,  $d$ satisfies:

1. $d(x, y) \geq 0$
2. $d(x, y) = 0 \iff x = y$
3. $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$
4. $d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$

It isn't difficult to see that axioms $2$, $3$, and $4$ imply $1$, so $1$ doesn't add anything to the definition and is superfluous. Why then do we keep 1 as an axiom in the definition of a metric instead of it being a corollary to the definition?

Comment: Perspicuousness.

Comment: or better yet, just define $d$ to be a function $d\colon E\times E \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: btw, you probably mean $\forall x,y,z\in E$.

Comment: Convention, history...

Answer (score 4):

In fact, it is enough to require only that
$$d(x,y)=0 \textrm{ if and only if } x=y$$
and
$$d(y,z)\leq d(x,y) +d(x,z)$$

All other properties of the metric follow from these, including 
nonnegativity.

Comment: How does (3) follow from these?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the slight of hand now. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously no need ;

But since "Metric Space" deals with  distance function and the distance between any two objects is always non-negative so the axiom is added to mark its significance.