# Is there a metric like space $(X,d)$ where $d$ only satisfies triangle inequality, and not the first two conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Is there a metric like space $(X,d)$ where $d$ only satisfies triangle inequality, and not the first two conditions of a metric? That is, $d:X\times X\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ only satisfies:
$$d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Related: there is a minimalistic formulation of being a metric, which is that a function $d:X\times X\to\Bbb R$ is a metric if and only if it satisfies: 1) $\forall x,\forall y, (d(x,y)=0\leftrightarrow x=y)$; 2) $\forall x,\forall y,\forall z, d(x,z)\le d(y,x)+d(y,z)$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000046/metric-space-axioms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $X=\mathbb R$ and $$d(x,y)=|x|+1$$

This definition satisfies the triangle inequality but is not a metric. It is neither symmetric nor does it satisfy $d(x,x)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the first two conditions here are $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ and $d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$. If so, consider $$d:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}^{+},\quad (x,y)\mapsto \begin{cases}2&\text{if $x\leq y$}\\
0&\text{if $x>y$}\end{cases}.$$